# Unsolved system of Nonlinear equations (bvp)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

$\frac{df}{dr }=\frac{a}{r }\sin{f}$

$-\frac{1}{r}\frac{da}{dr}={\cos{f}-A}$

$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dA}{dr})-\frac{1}{r}\frac{da}{dr }=A(\sin{f})^2$

which must satisfy the boundary conditions

$f(0) = 0, f(\infty) = \pi/2$

$a(0) = n, a(\infty) = 0$

$A(0) = cte., A(\infty) = 0$

$A'(0) = 0, A'(\infty) = 0$

being $n ∈ Z$. Thus, I tried to solve numerically as follows:

```
n = 1; eps = 10^-10; end = 10;
ode1 = f'[r] - (a[r]* Sin[f[r]])/r == 0;
ode2 = a'[r]/r + (Cos[f[r]] - A[r]) == 0;
ode3 = 1/r D[r*A'[r], r] - a'[r]/r == A[r]* (Sin[f[r]])^2;
bcs = {a[eps] == n, f[end] == Pi/2, A'[eps] == eps, A[end] == eps};
sol = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, bcs}, {a, f, A}, {r, eps, end}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}}]
Plot[Re[{a[r], f[r]}] /. sol // Evaluate, {r, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Re[{A[r], A'[r]}] /. sol // Evaluate, {r, 0, 10}]
```

and I have obtained the plots:

[image]
[image]

So, the problem is that I can't satisfy all the boundary conditions. On the other hand, I can solve this problem using Maple software, but I would like to be able to reproduce the plots in Mathematica as well.

In Maple the solutions are well behaved, already verified and have the following form:
[image]

Therefore, we observe that my plots in Mathematica for a(r) and f(r) are similar to Maple (even if they do not have the same precision), but the plots of the functions A(r) and A'(r) are significantly different.

How can I improve my program to reproduce the correct Maple result? I appreciate any help.

EDIT: Maple's plot in the figure for the derivative of `A[r]` was made for `-A'[r]`

Comment: **and I have obtained the plots:** I do not get anything close to what you show when running your code as in on V 13.3.1. This is what it gives ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boexb.png)

Comment: Sorry @Nasser, in the Mathematica plot I used `end=10`. I already edited in my question.

Comment: @Andrey Your Maple plot `A[r], A'[r]` seems to be wrong. The slope of `A[r]` is negative!

Comment: @ UlrichNeumann, You're right, Maple's plot in the figure above was made with `-A'[r]`. I already added this observation to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your ode's as first order system and try `Method->"FiniteElement"`

```
n = 1; eps = 10^-10; end = 10;
ode1 = f'[r] - (a[r]*Sin[f[r]])/r == 0;
ode2 = a'[r]/r + (Cos[f[r]] - A[r]) == 0;
ode3 = 1/r D[r*As[r], r] - a'[r]/r == A[r]*(Sin[f[r]])^2;
ode4 = As[r] == A'[r];

bcs = {a[eps] == n, f[end] == Pi/2, As[eps] == eps, A[end] == eps};
afA = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, bcs}, {a, f, A, As}, 
{r,eps, end}  , 
Method -> {"FiniteElement" , "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> .1}] //Quiet
```

Mathematica gives a warning "NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help." but the result looks promising(hopefully)

```
Plot[Evaluate[Through[afA [t]]], {t, eps, end},PlotStyle -> {Red,Darker[Green], Blue, Black}, PlotLegends -> {"a[r]", "f[r]", "A[r]", "A'[r]"} ]
```

[image]

Hopt it helps!

**addendum**

case `n=5` (increased  `end=15`) evaluates accordingly

```
n = 5; eps = 10^-10; end = 15;
ode1 = f'[r] - (a[r]*Sin[f[r]])/r == 0;
ode2 = a'[r]/r + (Cos[f[r]] - A[r]) == 0;
ode3 = 1/r D[r*As[r], r] - a'[r]/r == A[r]*(Sin[f[r]])^2;
ode4 = As[r] == A'[r];
 
bcs = {a[eps] == n, f[end] == Pi/2, As[eps] == eps, A[end] == eps};
afA = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, bcs}, {a, f, A, As}, {r, 
   eps, end}  , 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement" , "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> .1}] 

Plot[Evaluate[Through[afA [t]]], {t, eps, end}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Darker[Green], Blue, Black}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"a[r]", "f[r]", "A[r]", "A'[r]"} ]
```

[image]

Case `n=10 and end=20` evaluates too

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I still have a question and maybe you can help with this problem too. Were you able to test for other values of `n (a(0)=n)`? I tried here and couldn't get it to run for `n>=5`. If it runs up to `n=10` it would be enough for my purposes. If you can overcome this problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: My code (see my asnwer) for different valus of `n` evaluates without problems!

Comment: @Andeay I added case `n=5` in my answer

Comment: Thanks again. Your answer together with the part added later helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!